# Keras custom loss function causes TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, differentiation

1. Why when I am trying to create my own loss function using Keras backend

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.max(y_true, y_pred) / K.min(y_true, y_pred))
```

and pass to the Keras neural network, I get

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'reduction_indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

2. As far as I know, we should use Keras backend functions in custom loss because keras have to differentiate the loss function, but how do they differentiate Max and Min functions that have no derivative?

Comment: Can you please share the entire code so that we can reproduce your issue. Thanks!